# Функция на с++ консольное приложение

Tags: c++

консольное приложение на с++

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#pragma hdrstop

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int suma(int);
{for(int x=1; x<=10; x++)
cout<<suma(x)<<"  ";
return 0;
}
int suma(int y);
{return y+y;}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
[C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(20): E2040 Declaration terminated incorrectly
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 3):

уберите точку с запятой в 20 строку (`int suma(int y);`)

Answer (score 2):

У функции main есть тело, но нет заголовка. Надо так:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) //Обрати внимание на отсутствие точки с запятой
{
    for(int x=1; x<=10; x++)
        cout<<suma(x)<<"  ";
    return 0;
}
```

И как тебе написали ранее, убери ";" в предпоследней строке.